# Submitting BFH-DATEPICKER Value with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am having a problem with submitting the date value with bootstrap form helper. So, for the markup I have this input tags

```
<label for="delivDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><font color="black">DELIVERY DATE</font></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" class="bfh-datepicker" data-date="today"></div>
    </div>
```

So, I need to submit deliveryDate value with $_POST method. I can do this with no problem with  tag. But, in this case, I need to use  in order to make the formhelpers work.

plus, if I want to show the passed value with print_r($_POST), I can see nothing is there related to that date value.

Please help me on how to achieve this,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

> name="deliveryDate"

to

> data-name="deliveryDate"

so your code will be like this:

```
<label for="delivDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><font color="black">DELIVERY DATE</font></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="deliveryDate" data-name="deliveryDate" class="bfh-datepicker" data-date="today"></div>
</div>
```